# Forcing a password change on OpenBSD

Tags: ssh, openbsd, password-management, password-policy

On OpenBSD 5.6 I need to provision a number of user accounts with default passwords. I would like users, upon their first SSH login, to be forced to change their passwords from the default.

On CentOS and Debian I can do this using `chage -d 0 $username`.

It appears from the login.conf manual that I should be able to accomplish the same thing on OpenBSD with something like:

- `usermod -f 1 $username` or
- `usermod -f "Jan 1 2015" $username`

Setting it that way does prompt the appropriate change in `userinfo $username`, but logging in as $username via SSH does not actually enforce a password change - it opens the shell quite happily, oblivious to the password having been marked inactive above.

Some posts from 2000 talk through [writing a wrapper login shell](http://www.monkey.org/openbsd/archive/misc/0012/msg00054.html) to force a password change. That said, given the obvious scaffolding in `usermod` and `chpass`, it seems that this is built-in, but not documented as widely as the Linux equivalents.

Can a BSD pro shed some light on the conventional approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

According to `login.conf (5)`, the default grace period for an expired (aka "dead") password is 0.  Unless that value is set in `/etc/login.conf`, a user cannot login to change her password if the current system date is greater than the 6th field of a user's password entry in `/etc/master.passwd` - refer to `passwd (5)`.

To solve the problem you will need to specify a date formatted in number of seconds since the epoch that falls within your grace period of choice, e.g. 2 weeks, which you will also configure in `/etc/login.conf`.  To manually pick a password expiration time of yesterday we can use:

```
# date -d yesterday +%s
1463597700
```

And then plug that value into field #6 in `/etc/master.passwd` by using `vipw`.  The relevant line will then look something like this:

```
user:$2b$08$01234567890abcdef:1000:1000::1463597700:0:user:/home/user:/bin/ksh
```

Running usermod like you indicated (`usermod -f "May 17 2016" user`) will do essentially the same thing, but in both cases `/etc/login.conf` must also be changed by appending the following to the `default:\` or relevant section for your class of user:

```
    :password-dead=2w:\
    :password-warn=2w:
```

The first line allows a grace period of two weeks for the user to change her password; the second line will issue warnings that a user's password is scheduled to expire.  If expired, your users will see something like the following:

```
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing local password for user.
Old password:
New password:
Retype new password:
Connection to openbsd-server closed.
```

You can also configure `:passwordtime=7776000:` in `/etc/login.conf` to enforce an additional password change every 90 days.
Note that if you require additional checks on users' password complexity, like forbidding password reuse, you should install and configure `passwordqc` from packages, or another password checker program.